# Error in Windows 7: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, ssl-certificate, httpwebrequest

I have the following problem:
If I open with the web browser the address https://info.protectiacivila.ro/test.php
then the text "Hello!" is displayed.

I wrote the following click event handler in a windows forms application (target: .NET 4.5):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Uri uri = new Uri("https://info.protectiacivila.ro/test.php");
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
  try {
    string strResponse;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
      strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(strResponse);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

The above method should display the message "Hello!"
It works perfectly in Windows 10.
This means that the SSL certificate is valid.

However, in Windows 7 it displays the error message:
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

What can I do to make the above method work in Windows 7 as well?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a patched windows 7? Looks like [TLS 1.2 comes with Win7 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi)

Comment: I have Win 7 SP1 64 bit.  The update KB3140245 is installed.  Should I do anything more?

Comment: Not sure, give that link a deep read. You know Windows 7 support [ended in January 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057281/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020) right? It is no longer receiving security updated and you should consider migrating your machines to more updated operative systems.

Answer (score 7):

it seems that Windows 7 SP1 supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2 but it´s not enabled by default. This error also appears e.g. when you want to use GIT on Windows 7. The solution is to enable it via registry:

1. You need to create a registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
```

2. Add a DWORD 32bit with value `DisabledByDefault`

Source: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3008/How-do-I-enable-TLS-1-2-on-Windows-7.html

Comment: Fantastic! I was unable to use Git anymore with Bitbucket... worked for me too, Thank you!

Comment: This fixed my error "fatal: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." when I tried to `git pull` from Windows 7.